# How to arrange lines into colums of csv file with python?

Tags: python, csv, dynamic, opensuse

I am a chemistry student and I am interested in performing conformational analysis of molecules. I have performed a Potential Energy Surface Scan on the cumaric acid in order to find the most stable conformer. With this simple process the  different spatial arrangements due to rotations of groups of atoms about a bond are visualized. The image **pes_molecule.png** of the molecule  shows clearly the two varying dihedrals of the chain.

The program used for this purpose is called Gaussian 09 and gives the following **pes5part.csv** output for the first five conformers:

```
                   1         2         3         4         5
 Eigenvalues --  -570.08934-570.08821-570.08676-570.08521-570.08384
       B1           1.38384   1.38327   1.38324   1.38348   1.38413
       B2           1.38571   1.38662   1.38692   1.38687   1.38631
       A2         119.68274 119.74315 119.80026 119.84218 119.85816
       B3           1.39004   1.38856   1.38754   1.38685   1.38683
       A3         119.90377 119.88911 119.86542 119.83707 119.82679
       D3         359.78590 359.83552 359.88306 359.93484 359.98413
       B4           1.37736   1.37902   1.38023   1.38107   1.38117
       A4         119.75636 119.73537 119.72486 119.72923 119.74312
       D4           0.71367   0.72647   0.69117   0.56509   0.38069
       B5           1.39645   1.39466   1.39330   1.39215   1.39158
       A5         121.33129 121.30763 121.28873 121.27166 121.23298
       D5           0.35956   0.44698   0.45240   0.42630   0.33448
       B6           1.47220   1.47528   1.47926   1.48347   1.48738
       A6         122.40820 121.98088 121.61637 121.36363 121.16036
       D6         180.48284 181.09688 181.65183 182.01495 181.86758
       B7           1.32697   1.32601   1.32486   1.32369   1.32268
       A7         126.15279 125.45399 124.91354 124.58356 124.35302
       D7         326.35068 316.35068 306.35068 296.35068 286.35068
       B8           1.47594   1.47706   1.47838   1.47958   1.48079
       A8         119.99708 120.12965 120.23195 120.29720 120.33716
       D8         180.53457 180.77470 180.92143 180.91869 180.76068
       B9           1.07411   1.07413   1.07416   1.07418   1.07420
       A9         118.93985 118.98599 119.01911 119.04122 119.05329
       D9         181.37285 181.38492 181.22672 180.94401 180.58221
       B10          1.34694   1.34770   1.34843   1.34907   1.34959
       A10        122.64744 122.58131 122.55418 122.55000 122.56749
       D10        180.42161 180.46502 180.42820 180.34924 180.21926
       B11          1.07626   1.07630   1.07630   1.07624   1.07612
       A11        119.03402 119.08722 119.10807 119.12392 119.13418
       D11        179.35212 179.21303 179.20177 179.31786 179.55673
       B12          1.07697   1.07704   1.07710   1.07715   1.07720
       A12        120.07413 120.05334 120.01240 119.97693 119.94390
       D12        180.48654 180.55485 180.52338 180.39366 180.25905
       B13          1.07508   1.07529   1.07540   1.07548   1.07561
       A13        119.03861 119.18885 119.28342 119.31016 119.29960
       D13        181.28569 181.16448 180.90103 180.58626 180.30590
       B14          0.94291   0.94286   0.94282   0.94279   0.94274
       A14        111.19697 111.19860 111.17512 111.14446 111.13678
       D14        359.87694 359.98739 360.03935 359.94679 360.14975
       B15          1.33041   1.33009   1.32973   1.32951   1.32933
       A15        111.93106 111.92554 111.91202 111.89198 111.87131
       D15        180.31345 180.31345 180.31345 180.31345 180.31345
       B16          1.19235   1.19199   1.19165   1.19132   1.19107
       A16        126.00937 125.96822 125.92197 125.88559 125.85792
       D16          0.53326   0.61269   0.54073   0.55376   0.45438
       B17          1.07741   1.07759   1.07781   1.07807   1.07828
       A17        116.61938 117.00542 117.31889 117.52706 117.69428
       D17        149.32579 139.91922 130.07838 119.74879 108.88744
       B18          1.07393   1.07424   1.07440   1.07445   1.07448
       A18        123.00819 122.72745 122.54598 122.45741 122.42974
       D18          0.14076   0.61929   0.95343   1.10958   0.96334
       B19          0.94770   0.94770   0.94774   0.94780   0.94787
       A19        108.07785 108.09603 108.12787 108.16255 108.20337
       D19        180.24961 180.28903 180.28314 180.25552 180.18273
```

**My goal is to create a csv file** with the following arrangement:

```
    Eigenvalues    D7         D15
    -570.08934  326.35068  180.31345
    -570.08821  316.35068  180.31345
    -570.08676  306.35068  180.31345
    -570.08521  296.35068  180.31345
    -570.08384  286.35068  180.31345
```

The reason I need this is to create the 3D PES graph of the energy and the two dihedrals and afterwards to retrieve the conformer with the lowest energy.
For this purpose I have created the following script:

```
#! /usr/bin/python2.7

import csv
import re

ifile =open('pes5part.csv', 'rb')
infile = csv.reader(ifile)

for line in open('pes5part.csv'):
    rec = line.strip()
    if rec.startswith('Eigenvalues') or rec.startswith('D7') or rec.startswith('D15'):
        print line
```

When the script runs the following is printed into the terminal:

```
 Eigenvalues --  -570.08934 -570.08821 -570.08676 -570.08521 -570.08384

       D7         326.35068 316.35068 306.35068 296.35068 286.35068

       D15        180.31345 180.31345 180.31345 180.31345 180.31345
```

So in order to proceed I need your help in order to arrange the values of the first line of the eigenvalues in the first column. Then the values of the second line of angle D7 to the second column and finally the values of angle D15 to the third column as depicted at **my goal csv file ** above.ccs

The complete PES scan file output from Gaussian with all 361 conformers is the **pesFULL.csv**:
The final complete desired PES file created by hand with all 361 conformers after 5 hours of typing is **pes.ods**
while the final PES graphs are depicted in the files **pes_graph1.png** and **pes_graph2.png**

I have attached all above files inside the shared dropbox folder
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/5185f19tifpfr8s/AAB8cj0-niTFGbfGtEvjmfdGa?dl=0

Thank you in advance developers for any suggestion or help.

Comment: this sounds like just applying a transpose right?

Comment: yes this is what I need.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very basic example, but it should do the job. Pay attention to use the right delimiter. You can modify the print statement to get the right formatting.

CSV:
CSV stands for Comma Separated Values, but there are at least three possible separators in CSV files. Tools and libraries can use semicolons, commas or the tab character as the separator. Depending on with which separator the file was created you have to make sure to use the same separator when reading it. The csv library in python calls the separator delimiter.
Since the input file wasn't posted I can't know which separator is being used in it.

```
import csv

D = list(csv.reader(open(r"pes5part.csv"), delimiter=";"))
for l in zip(*filter(lambda e: e[0].strip() in ["Eigenvalues", "D7", "D15"], D)):
    print "\t".join(l)
```

Of course doing it step-wise is not necessary, but this way I find it easier to read.

Upon further study of your question and example, i think the issue is that although the file has the csv extensions, it's not a proper CSV.
So try this instead:

```
import re

splitter = re.compile("\s+")
D = [splitter.split(a) for a in open(r"pes5part.csv").readlines()]
for l in zip(*filter(lambda e: e[0] in ["Eigenvalues", "D7", "D15"], D)):
    print "\t".join(l)
```

Comment: Thank for the response. Could you provide me some explanation about your script and especially the delimeter option in my case because I run it as you posted and nothing happened.

Comment: @ManolisSemidalas, check your input file with a normal texteditor (even notepad could work) to see which separator is being used, adapt the the delimiter argument accordingly

Comment: @ManolisSemidalas, sorry but I can't access dropbox from work

Comment: I appreciate your help. I used your script for both files https://www.dropbox.com/s/frrtesgin43jp3p/NEW_pes.csv?dl=0 and https://www.dropbox.com/s/z4lsiniu8lgz9vy/pesFULL.csv?dl=0               However despite the fact that the script run without any error , unfortunately no print output is provided. I would be grateful if you could provide some extra explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using Python's powerful data analysis toolkit, [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/index.html), where you can effortlessly [transpose](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.transpose.html) rows to columns:

```
import pandas as pd

# IMPORT DATA FRAME FROM CSV (ASSUMING NO HEADER)
chemistryData = pd.read_csv("C:\\Path\\To\\pes5part.csv",
                            header=None, names=['Type', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5'])

# FILTER NEEDED ROWS AND CONCATENATE TO NEW DATA FRAME
chemistryFilteredData = pd.concat([chemistryData[chemistryData['Type']=='Eigenvalues'],
                                   chemistryData[chemistryData['Type']=='D7'],
                                   chemistryData[chemistryData['Type']=='D15']], axis=0)

# TRANSPOSE DATA FRAME
chemistryTransposedData = chemistryFilteredData.transpose()

# OUTPUT NEW DATA FRAME TO CSV
chemistryTransposedData.to_csv("C:\\Path\\To\\tranposedfile.csv",
                               header=False)

print(chemistryTransposedData)
```

Output as follows:

```
Type  Eigenvalues        D7       D15
1       -570.0893  326.3507  180.3134
2       -570.0882  316.3507  180.3134
3       -570.0868  306.3507  180.3134
4       -570.0852  296.3507  180.3134
5       -570.0838  286.3507  180.3134
```

Comment: your script works for the NEW_pes.csv which is modified from the original .txt Gaussian output to .csv. It can be downloaded here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/frrtesgin43jp3p/NEW_pes.csv?dl=0   However, I need to perform the same procedure for every 5 conformers until i reach the final one, for example the 361 in the Gaussian output file that can be downloaded here:                      https://www.dropbox.com/s/z4lsiniu8lgz9vy/pesFULL.csv?dl=0               I would be grateful if you could explain # FILTER NEEDED ROWS AND CONCATENATE TO NEW DATA FRAME or if loop process should be used.